# read more function not working when text has some HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery code for show more/show less, it works fine for simple text. but its not working when text have some p html tags.
When its plan tex then its work fine, but when its html tags, then its not working.
Please check the below code, I have added the html and as well as js code

```
<span class="my-message">
 <p style="text-align: left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
 invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo 
 duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,  no sea 
 takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

 <p style="text-align: left;"><br></p>
 <p style="text-align: left;">Duis autem vel 
  eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie 
  consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero 
   eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent 
  luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla 
  facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
  elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore 
  magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p style="text-align: left;"><br></p>
  <p style="text-align: left;">Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis 
    nostrud exerci tation ullamco luptatum zzril delenit augue duis 
    dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
 </span>

    <script>
    var th = new showHideText('.my-message', {
        charQty     : 250,
        ellipseText : "...",
    });
    </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f8xt9j32/

```
function showHideText(sSelector, options) {
 // Def. options
 var defaults = {
     charQty     : 100,
     ellipseText : "...",
     moreText    : "Show more",
     lessText    : "Show less"
 };

 var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

 var s = this;

     s.container = $(sSelector);
     s.containerH = s.container.height();

     s.container.each(function() {
         var content = $(this).html();

         if(content.length > settings.charQty) {

             var visibleText = content.substr(0, settings.charQty);
             var hiddenText  = content.substr(settings.charQty, content.length - settings.charQty);

             var html = visibleText
                      + '<span class="moreellipses">' +
                        settings.ellipseText
                      + '</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' +
                        hiddenText
                      + '</span><a href="" class="morelink">' +
                        settings.moreText
                      + '</a></span>';

             $(this).html(html);
         }

     });

     s.showHide = function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
             $(this).removeClass("less");
             $(this).html(settings.moreText);

             $(this).prev().fadeToggle('fast', function() {
                 $(this).parent().prev().fadeIn();
             });
         } else {
             $(this).addClass("less");
             $(this).html(settings.lessText);

             $(this).parent().prev().hide();
             $(this).prev().fadeToggle('fast');
         }
     }

     $(".morelink").bind('click', s.showHide);
}
/*------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Your code is actually working. I have reversed show less and show more texts. Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/djnf7ep8/

Comment: it's not working correctly. Because it should show only the first few lines and after clicking on the show more then it should show other text.